# entropy-like measure to quantify the robustness of random forest prediction, using fraction of probability

Tags: classification, random-forest, entropy

Imagine I have performed a random forest to classify according to three classes: A, B, and C.

My correct get for a given sample is [1, 0, 0], because it belongs to class 1.

I have two different models that correctly predict the sample as "A", with the same fraction of votes:
Model 1: [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]
Model 2: [0.5, 0.45, 0.05]

I would say that model 1 is better than model 2 because there is more difference between his first guess (A=0.5) and his second guess (B=0.3). While in the second model the probabilities of A and B are very close so I would expect that testing more samples the probability of a misscall of a A sample as B is higher.

What measure could I use to quantify this?

The entropy of the two model would be the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you calculated Gini Impurity? It tells you the likelihood of of you misclassifying.

**Model 1: Gini Impurity** = 1 - (0.5^2 + 0.3^2 + 0.2^2) = 0.62

**Model 2: Gini Impurity** = 1 - (0.5^2 + 0.45^2 + 0.05^2) = 0.545

Since Model 2 has a lower Gini Impurity, it is better at predicting the correct class. This is because it has a lower probability of misclassifying.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't actually computing correctly gene impurity because I did not know it worked also when having more than 2 classes. However your calculations are wrong:

 Gini impurity model 1 = 1 - (0.5^2 + 0.3^2 + 0.2^2)= 0.62;

 Gini impurity model 2= 1 - (0.5^2 + 0.45^2 + 0.05^2)= 0.545


Actually model 2 is better than model 1 because it has lower gini impurity. While the first model has higher impurity and can misslabel in similar samples A with B

Answer (score 0):

In the end the accurate metrics I was looking for was Gini Impurity (the lowest the best) calculated as 1 - (sum ofthe probability of each classes squared). This gives a higher score (= worse model) when there are more options close to each other